# What is a strategy to implement this URL input analysis feature?

Tags: javascript, api, parsing, input

I found this cool feature on digg.com, where you can input a news URL and it will nearly instantaneously give you the title, the summary, and the image from the news story.

I don't need all these features but I would like to abstract out just the title.

I don't have the resources to download the entire website and say parse it for this information but was wondering if there was a way to get just the title ... using the client's machine, i.e. browser.

Is there an API available that might help with this?

The similar feature is found at digg.com/news after hitting the add button at the top:

[image]

Comment: you can't get that just using the browsers api - you'll have to have some sort of backend processing it for you

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "browsers api" ... i was referring to an external API, i.e. like the google API that will provide a favicon given a domain.

Comment: asking for 3rd party resources is off topic

Comment: Once again I'm not sure what you mean by "3rd party".  Who is party 1 and who is party 2?  I see many answers on SO that use an API.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_person — The first and second parties are you (asking the question) and the stackoverflow community (who you seek answers from). A third party is anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have the resources to download the entire website and say parse it for this information

That would be the reliable way to do it.

You could get a performance boost by downloading only the first  bytes of the page (by making a [range request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests), but you risk missing the `<title>` element if it exists beyond those bytes.

> if there was a way to get just the title ... using the client's machine, i.e. browser.

No. The [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) prevents this.